# Trying to reference files in different folder in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

**The Scenario:**

I have the following structure in my Angular project:

```
Project
  Folder1
    tsconfig.json
    Folder1.1
      file1.1.1
    Folder1.2
      file1.2.1
  Folder2
    tsconfig.json
    file2.1
```

`tsconfig.json` in `Folder1` contains

```
"paths": {
  "Folder1.2/*": [
    "../Folder1.2/*"
  ],
}
```

so that `file1.1.1` can reference `file1.2.1` as `Folder1.2/file1.2.1` rather than `.../Folder1.2/file1.2.1`.

**The Problem:**

`file2.1` needs to use `file1.1.1`. When I build the project, `file2.1` throws the error that it can't find `Folder1.2/file1.2.1`.

**What I've Tried:**

I assumed this was just because `file2.1` doesn't have an alias for `Folder1.2` the way the files in `Folder1` do. So in `tsconfig.json` in `Folder2` I added

```
"paths": {
  "Folder1.2/*": [
    "../Folder1/Folder1.2/*"
  ],
}
```

I still get the same errors.

Does anyone know how I should approach this?

Comment: Look into the `projectReferences` feature of tsconfig.json.

Comment: Hi Aluan, I actually found out from the project leader than I shouldn't be accessing properties of another project in my current project anyway, but I did look into `projectReferences` and I think that's what I was looking for. Thanks!